# Adding buttons in Group on ExapndedListView

Tags: android

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpMDw.png) How to Add two Imagebuttons inside ExpandableListView.
These 2 buttons should be seen after Group is expanded by clicking on it.
After this two-button, normal child items will be displayed.

Any Idea about adding the button inside the Group?
Android Kotlin or java

Thanks
Sc

Comment: Looks like your new to Android follow this tutorial 
https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ this might help you

Comment: I know how to add child items and do other stuff with ExpandedListView. My problem is adding button at the top of child items. See the attached image. you will get the idea. Thanks

Comment: you can create buttons in the group view of the `ExplandableListView`